# VB user controls not resizing in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vb6, resize

I'm updating a vb6 application to run in windows 8, and one of the issues is user control windows not resizing (via the window edge drag handles). It works fine under other OSes.

The same issue plagues the main project window.

The elements of the window are controlled in this function, but the window itself doesn't respond to resizing.

```
Private Sub UserControl_Resize()
If g_ShuttingDown Then Exit Sub
' Test for zero size
If ScaleWidth = 0 Or ScaleHeight = 0 Then Exit Sub

' Min size
'If ScaleWidth < iMIN_FORM_WIDTH Then UserControl.Width = iMIN_FORM_WIDTH
'If ScaleWidth < iMIN_FORM_HEIGHT Then UserControl.Height = iMIN_FORM_HEIGHT

' Form dimensions
Dim x, y, w, H As Long
x = ScaleLeft
y = ScaleTop
w = ScaleWidth
H = ScaleHeight

picTitleBar.Move 0, 0, w - 30, 240
imgTitleBar.Move 0, 0, picTitleBar.Width, 240
lblCaption.Move 45, 15
imgClose.Move picTitleBar.Width - imgClose.Width - 60, 60

chkVerbose.Move 15, picTitleBar.Top + picTitleBar.Height
cmdClear.Move chkVerbose.Left + chkVerbose.Width, chkVerbose.Top
chkPause.Move cmdClear.Left + cmdClear.Width, chkVerbose.Top

Messages.Move 15, chkVerbose.Top + chkVerbose.Height, w - 30, H - (chkVerbose.Top + chkVerbose.Height)
```

End Sub

Any ideas how I might get these windows to respond to the resize event properly?

Comment: Please provide more detail.  What kind of controls? How are they supposed to resize?

Comment: When grabbing the edge of a window, and dragging to resize it, the window does not respond.

Comment: Are you using VB 6 or VB.Net?

Comment: vb6 sorry, clicked the wrong tag

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in debugger? Any clues from there?

Comment: the resize handle appears, but when I click and drag it disapears, and the resize event is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u need download **new fixed dll** for **vb** in **win 8** or need access permision for vb6.exe to allow all actions .

and maybe u sholude be disabled win 8 theme to vb work good .

i have more problems with vb6in win8 but when i disabled themes in win 7 or win 8 many of my problems sloved .